# ScrollPanes in JavaFX 8 always have gray background

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

When I upgraded by JavaFX app from JavaFX 2 to JavaFX 8, I noticed that ScrollPanes always showed up as gray rectangles, even with a background color set or the background set to be transparent.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I found the solution in this discussion: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3538169

First I needed this:

```
.scroll-pane > .viewport {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Then I could set the background color to whatever I like.  In this case, I'm making all ScrollPane backgrounds transparent:

```
.scroll-pane {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: See [here](http://admedfx.blogspot.com/2014/04/fx-22-to-fx-80-part-6-scrollpane.html) for other JavaFX 2 to JavaFX 8 issues.

Comment: Setting the color in your first snippet above worked for me-didn't need the second

Answer (score 27):

Came acroos this just now, it's not working with **-fx-background-color**, but it is with **-fx-background**

```
.scroll-pane {
   -fx-background: #FFFFFF;
   -fx-border-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer, as the current accepted answer is more of a hack-around

Answer (score 5):

To alter borders, you would have to use "fx-background-color" . 
To modify the viewport's background color, you should modify the "fx-background" attribute.

I used white for both colors :

`scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-background: rgb(255,255,255);\n -fx-background-color: rgb(255,255,255)");`

Answer (score 0):

In-source approach:

Once it's added to the scene/stage, you can trigger off the width or height property to get access to the viewport styling.

```
    ScrollPane myPane = new ScrollPane();

    myPane.widthProperty().addListener((o) -> {
        Node vp = logMessagePane.lookup(".viewport");
        vp.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#434547;");
    });
```